# Text over image in Android layout like messages button in Facebook

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a notification `Button` in Android `Activity` as the same as notification button in Facebook. I tried `ImageButton` and `Button` to do this but I failed to display the text drawn over the image in the same layer. Why?

Comment: Do you mean the little red circle containing the count or the bubble containing the whole notification text? you're being very ambiguous here

Comment: yes you are right you got what i am need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm getting your question right and you need the red circle containing the count of notifications, you create a drawable and use it as a background for your TextView

Here is a sample rounded-edges rectangular shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:left="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
    </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#F00"/>
    </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then all you need is to use that as a background for your TextView

**Edit**: use FrameLayout to make the notification appear over the ImageView

```
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/image" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/notification"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                    android:background="@drawable/red_notification_frame"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:minWidth="15dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                    android:paddingRight="1dp"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </FrameLayout>
```

And change the layout_gravity for the TextView to control its position over the image.

Comment: no you do not got is i want make this screen in this link https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ4MdSPm7hFQlijZKKnStYuyLy2m4u94pPFKdX2ktMt58Bi5fq2

Comment: @SaidGamal use FrameLayout to make the TextView with the red background on top of your ImageView

Comment: yes i am already did it but how make the text view over the image not above it this is my question many thanks for your help

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what do you mean by "over and not above"?

Comment: i am mean the bottom edge of text will be inside the image view.

Comment: @SaidGamal I edited the answer to include what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a permanent text to be displayed over an Image, a shortcut option is to use a Image editing software and write the text over the Image.
Then use a ImageButton and place the Image.

Answer (score 0):

I modified an answer and came up with a solution

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="102dp"
    android:layout_width="102dp"
   android:padding="15dp">
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/envelope" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="12dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/myImageView"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/myImageView"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myImageView"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myImageView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

The xml style, put it in the drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <stroke
android:width="1dp"
android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
<solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
<padding
android:left="1dp"
android:right="1dp"
android:top="1dp" />
<corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

In my case when the text is beyong three chars, I say 9+